# Worst case time complexity for the code

Tags: algorithm, vector, time-complexity, big-o

Why is the worst time complexity of the following code is O(N)?

```cpp
/* 
* V is sorted 
* V.size() = N
* The function is initially called as searchNumOccurrence(V, k, 0, N-1)
*/

int searchNumOccurrence(vector<int> &V, int k, int start, int end) {
  if (start > end) return 0;
  int mid = (start + end) / 2;
  if (V[mid] < k) return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, mid + 1, end);
  if (V[mid] > k) return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1);
  return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1) + 1 + searchNumOccurrence(V, k, mid + 1, end);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the worst case? the worst case will be that all element are the same and equals to `k`. Then you have to at least read all elements, which is `N`. Since most function calls increase the output by 1, there are about `N` function calls (some returns 0, but they don't spawn new calls). Therefore, the worst time complexity is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the worst case if all the numbers in the array are equal to k, then in this worst case, the recurrence relation shall be:

```
T(n) = 2*T(n/2)
```

This translates into `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The last case -

`return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1) + 1 + searchNumOccurrence(V, k, mid + 1, end);`

is the bottleneck step. 
Assuming all the values in the array are the same, we get the following relation :

```
T(N) = 2 * T(N/2) + constant
= 4 * T(N/4) + constant ( 2 * constant = another constant ) 
= 8 * T(N/8) + constant 
.....
= N * T(N/N) + constant 
= N + constant 
= O(N)
```